# Compare two String in Java with possible null/empty values, when one is null and another is empty it will return true

Tags: java, string, java-8, null

Looking for a way (OK with using Apache libs as well), to compare two String in Java with possible null/empty values, where the main requirement is when if one is `null` and another is empty `("")` it will return `true`.

Emphasizing - **any null/empty combination allowed**, and all the combinations would be considered a `true` statement.

```
one   | two  | res
------|------|-----
 ""   | ""   | true
 ""   | null | true
 null | ""   | true
 null | null | true
```

I've checked many related questions here, and they are not considering my main requirement.

Comment: Is any null/empty combination allowed, or are you looking e.g. only for the first string to be null and the second empty (or vice-versa) ?

Comment: `return one == null || one.isEmpty()? two == null || two.isEmpty(): one.equals(two);` That’s the literal translation of your conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```java
public static boolean isEqual(String one, String two) {
    // org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
    return StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(one, "")
            .equals(StringUtils.defaultIfEmpty(two, ""));
}
```

Output:

```
 one  | two  | res
------|------|-----
 ""   | ""   | true
 ""   | null | true
 null | null | true
```

---

Alternatives:

```java
public static boolean isEqual(String one, String two) {
    if (one == null) one = "";
    if (two == null) two = "";    
    return one.equals(two);
}
```

```java
public static boolean isEqual(String one, String two) {
    one = Objects.requireNonNullElse(one, "");
    two = Objects.requireNonNullElse(two, "");
    return one.equals(two);
}
```

Comment: There’s no need to use `Objects.equals(…)` when `null` has been substituted already. You can use `return (one == null ? "" : one).equals(two == null ? "" : two);` Or you use `return Objects.requireNonNullElse(one, "").equals(Objects.requireNonNullElse(two, ""));` which has a similar logic as the `StringUtils` approach but doesn’t require an external library.

Comment: I know it. But this syntax is not very clear. I prefer my implementation. But for `Objects.requireNonNullElse()` thank you.

Comment: “You can separate the `equals` call and the conditionals” (as you did in the edit) was also my first thought after reading your comment. Note that the good old `if` would also work, `if(one == null) one = ""; if(two == null) two =""; return one.equals(two);` I agree that the combined conditionals and `equals` call might be hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper class overriding `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`.

```
public final class StringWrapper {

  private final String value;

  private StringWrapper(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static StringWrapper ofValue(String value) {
    return new StringWrapper(value);
  }

  public static StringWrapper ofNull() {
    return ofValue(null);
  }

  public static StringWrapper ofEmpty() {
    return ofValue("");
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
      return 0;
    }
    return value.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof StringWrapper wrapper)) {
      return false;
    }
    String value1 = Objects.requireNonNullElse(value, "");
    String value2 = Objects.requireNonNullElse(wrapper.value, "");
    return Objects.equals(value1, value2);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Wrapper - " + value;
  }
}
```

And tests covering the scenarios:

```
public class StringWrapperTests {

  @Test
  public void sameStringValues_ShouldReturnTrue() {
    StringWrapper first = StringWrapper.ofValue("a");
    StringWrapper second = StringWrapper.ofValue("a");
    assertEquals(first, second);
    assertEquals(second, first);
  }

  @Test
  public void differentValues_ShouldReturnFalse() {
    StringWrapper first = StringWrapper.ofValue("a");
    StringWrapper second = StringWrapper.ofValue("b");
    assertNotEquals(first, second);
    assertNotEquals(second, first);
  }

  @Test
  public void bothEmpty_ShouldReturnFalse() {
    StringWrapper first = StringWrapper.ofEmpty();
    StringWrapper second = StringWrapper.ofEmpty();
    assertEquals(first, second);
    assertEquals(second, first);
  }

  @Test
  public void firstNullSecondEmpty_ShouldReturnTrue() {
    StringWrapper first = StringWrapper.ofNull();
    StringWrapper second = StringWrapper.ofEmpty();
    assertEquals(first, second);
  }

  @Test
  public void firstEmptySecondNull_ShouldReturnTrue() {
    StringWrapper first = StringWrapper.ofEmpty();
    StringWrapper second = StringWrapper.ofNull();
    assertEquals(first, second);
  }

  @Test
  public void bothNull_ShouldReturnTrue() {
    StringWrapper first = StringWrapper.ofNull();
    StringWrapper second = StringWrapper.ofNull();
    assertEquals(first, second);
    assertEquals(second, first);
  }

  @Test
  public void firstNullSecondValue_ShouldReturnFalse() {
    StringWrapper first = StringWrapper.ofNull();
    StringWrapper second = StringWrapper.ofValue("qwerty");
    assertNotEquals(first, second);
  }

  @Test
  public void firstValueSecondNull_ShouldReturnFalse() {
    StringWrapper first = StringWrapper.ofValue("asd");
    StringWrapper second = StringWrapper.ofNull();
    assertNotEquals(first, second);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try to use the hutool

```
boolean answer(String str1, String str2) {
    if (StrUtil.isEmpty(str1) && StrUtil.isEmpty(str2)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (StrUtil.equals(str1, str2)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You need to indicate where `StrUtil` comes from by using the full package name.